# How to show image in PDF with HtmlRenderer?(The image is downloaded automatically when you enter the URL

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, html-renderer

I want to show pictures in PDF with HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp. I am using this example. https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer

I can show this link in PDF.
https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg

But I can't show this link in PDF. https://images.data.gov.sg/api/traffic-images/2016/02/96128cfd-ab9a-4959-972e-a5e74bb149a9.jpg

Because when you enter this link, the picture is downloaded automatically and is not displayed in the browser.

This code generates the PDF.

```
private void OnGeneratePdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PdfGenerateConfig config = new PdfGenerateConfig();
    config.PageSize = PageSize.A4;
    config.SetMargins(20);

    var doc = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(_mainControl.GetHtml(), config, null, DemoUtils.OnStylesheetLoad, HtmlRenderingHelper.OnImageLoadPdfSharp);
    var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    tmpFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tmpFile) + ".pdf";
    doc.Save(tmpFile);
    Process.Start(tmpFile);
}
```

This is the error I get when pasting the link.

[image: This is the error I get when pasting the link.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I solved the problem.

```
      public static void GeneratePDF(string htmlstr)
        {
            PdfGenerateConfig config = new PdfGenerateConfig();
            config.PageSize = PageSize.A4;
            var doc = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(htmlstr, config, null, null, OnImageLoadPdfSharp);
            var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            tmpFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tmpFile) + ".pdf";
            doc.Save(tmpFile);
            Process.Start(tmpFile);
        }

        public static void OnImageLoadPdfSharp(object sender, HtmlImageLoadEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var url = e.Src;
                var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
                client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), tmpFile);
                ResizeImage(tmpFile);
                e.Callback(XImage.FromFile(tmpFile));
            }
        }
```